# [java]Remove unecesarry Space

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing

i have a string with multiple space that is unnecessary, i want to remove that space and need an output in good structure. I need one space between words.
INPUT: there is number of spaces after number , before first words.. 5 new line, with @line there is a number of space

```
1





        An item one



        area city, country 
        type of area
        time of event 1

2





        An item one



        area  city, country 
        type of area
        time of event 1

3 ... idem
```

`

and what i want is the structure only like :

`An item one; area city, country; type of area; time of event 1;`

`An item two; area city, country; type of area; time of event 2;
.
.
.`

i try with 
`st.replaceAll("\n", "")`
but its not that i'm expected..
need help..

**Update partially SOLVED and already exist another problem**

1. Problem 1st

   ```
           s = s.replaceAll("\\n+", " ");
           s = s.trim();
           s = s.replaceAll(" \\s+", ";");
   ```

   Output:

`1 An item one; area city, country; type of area; time of event 1
2 An item one; area;city, country; type of area; time of event 1`

And now 2nd problem is exist, for example when there is exist more than 1 space in a words

`area  city` and the result give `area;city` , so help me for this...

Comment: Would recommend using delimiter

Comment: FAIL, your result is NOT as per your original question.  see my answer for correct way.

Comment: what if there are multiple spaces between words? trim wont remove that. trim only removes from right and left end

Comment: yes, im still fail, im just correct my post.... sorry.. i just remove [SOLVED] and the problem still exist

Comment: Please clarify, do you want ^number\r\n to be removed?

Comment: i need an output : `1 An item one; area city, country; type of area; time of event 1;` with and without number is not worried, main problem is remove lot of space

Comment: enough of this ever evolving question.  how can you code it if you do not even know what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "abc     def    agig";
    s=s.trim(); // thanks to Christian for the suggestion. 
    s= s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    System.out.println(s);

    O/P : abc def agig
```

Comment: I would definitely say that the space is not at the end or beginning.

Comment: If downvoters would be kind enough to leave a comment, I could learn a bit more.. :)

Comment: @Christian - Oops.. "" should have been " ". My bad. replace one or more occurances of " " with " ". Didn't see I had typed "".

Comment: Use `trim()` too, because OP string have trailing spaces.

Comment: Does `s= s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");` not replace trailing spaces?

Comment: @user2310289 - It replaces (say) more than one trailing whitespace with 1 whitespace. trim() removes all leading and trailing whitespaces..

Comment: @Christian - I got downvoted for using trim(). See first comment.. :)

Comment: Well, it's not clear since the trailing spaces in the OP string could be there because of formatting issues. You could point it out in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your required output:

INPUT:

```
An item one



area city, country
type of area
time of event 1
```

Use below:

> `st = st.replaceAll("\\r?\\n+",";");`

Output:

```
An item one;area city, country;type of area;time of event 1
```

Comment: it result `1 ;        ;          ;        ;        ;        ;            An item one;        ;        ;        ;            area city, country ;            type of area;            time of event 1        ;            
`

Comment: @user3145749 What is your input string?

Comment: @user3145749 have you used + in used regex as `\\r?\\n+`?

Comment: @enhaka can you give me exact input what you are using?

Comment: the exact input is show on my ask post.. INPUT: there is number of spaces after number , before first words.. 5 new line, with @line there is a number of space

Answer (score 0):

Goal is to go from multiple lines to semi colon seperated text and with extra spaces removed?

Maybe you need to use multiple lines of code. First get rid of extra new lines, then extra spaces and then put the semi colons in and join lines

So first replace all double new lines with single:

```
st = st.replace("\r", "\n"); // just in case you have windows new line
st = st.replace("\n\n", ); // optional, else string tokeizer will by default iggnore consecutive seperators
```

Now a string tokenizer that breaks on new line

```
logger.info("Initial :[[[" + st + "]]]");
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer (st, "\n");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (); //the final string, will be built here
boolean first = true;
while(st1.hasMoreTokens(){
    s = st1.nextToken();
    s = s.trim();
    s =  s.replace("  ", " ");//two spaces with one
    if(frist){
       first = false;
    }else{
        sb.append(";");
    }
    sb.append(s);
}
logger.info("Final :[[[" + sb + "]]]");
```

Note

1. this is not compiled code, just wrote it here for clarity
2. if you do not use logging you should, or use System.out.println ...

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

For example

```
System.out.println("abcd           ipsum          dolor \n sit.".replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

outputs

```
abcd ipsum dolor sit.
```